# how do i show favorites bar in microsoft edge?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

In the browser Microsoft Edge browser how do I show my favorites bar?

In the top right corner I see the three dots I clicked there then searched all around in the settings but don't seem to see a toggle switch. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the three dots (settings)
2. Scroll down and click `Settings`
3. Scroll down and click `View favorites settings`
4. Click `Show the favorites bar` so it reads `On`

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/see-your-favorites-bar#v1h=tab01)